# Resolving conflicting touches with multitouch

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touch, multi-touch

I have two sprites that rotate towards the point of touch. In `touchesBegan` I use if statements to check if the point of touch is within either of two X point ranges in order to separate the two sprite's rotations. For example, if the point of touch is within the left range then the left sprite rotates towards the point of touch. I use `touchesMoved` to update the rotation of the sprite. I then use `touchesEnded` to return the sprite to its original position.

The problem I'm facing is that if I drag my finger from left to the right and therefore cross from the left range to the right range then `touchesEnded` does not return the first sprite to its original position. I understand that this is due to the touch ending in the other range and then only correcting that other sprite. I've tried to solve this by adding an if statement in touchesMoved to correct the position if the touch is moved beyond one range and into the other.

It works until I use two fingers, one on each side of the screen to rotate both sprites differently at the same time. The sprites then jump back and forth from their current rotation to their original position uncontrollably. What would be the best approach to solve this?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        location = touch.location(in: self)
        let DegreesToRadians = Pi / 180

        let rightDeltaX = location.x - rightSprite.position.x
        let rightDeltaY = location.y - rightSprite.position.y
        let rightAngle = atan2(rightDeltaY, rightDeltaX)

        let leftDeltaX = location.x - leftSprite.position.x
        let leftDeltaY = location.y - leftSprite.position.y
        let leftAngle = atan2(leftDeltaY, leftDeltaX)

            if 0...768 ~= location.x {
                leftSprite.zRotation = leftAngle - 90 * DegreesToRadians
            }
            if 769...1536 ~= location.x {
                rightSprite.zRotation = rightAngle - 90 * DegreesToRadians
            }
    }
}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        location = touch.location(in: self)
        let DegreesToRadians = Pi / 180

        let rightDeltaX = location.x - rightSprite.position.x
        let rightDeltaY = location.y - rightSprite.position.y
        let rightAngle = atan2(rightDeltaY, rightDeltaX)

        let leftDeltaX = location.x - leftSprite.position.x
        let leftDeltaY = location.y - leftSprite.position.y
        let leftAngle = atan2(leftDeltaY, leftDeltaX)

            if 0...768 ~= location.x {
                leftSprite.zRotation = leftAngle - 90 * DegreesToRadians

                if !(769...1536 ~= location.x) {
                    rightSprite.zRotation = 0
                }
            }
            if 769...1536 ~= location.x {
                rightSprite.zRotation = rightAngle - 90 * DegreesToRadians

                if !(0...768 ~= location.x) {
                    leftSprite.zRotation = 0
                }
            }
    }
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        location = touch.location(in: self)

            if 0...768 ~= location.x {
                leftSprite.zRotation = 0
            }
            if 769...1536 ~= location.x {
                rightSprite.zRotation = 0
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: show some code, let's see your touch events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each "touch" in the UITouch Set that is passed to the function is a distinct touch event.  When using multiple touches simultaneously, each finger would be represented with a separate "touch" in the set.  Keep in mind that this is an unordered set.

In the code you provide, you retrieve the location of a single touch event.  You check if the x value of the touch's location is high, then within that condition, you also check if it is low.  But you're checking the same location, the same x value.  If the x value is 768 or below, it will *always* be "!(x > 769)".  If it is 769 or above, it will *always* be "not 768 or below".

Thus, for each touch event during the "move" function, no matter which side it's on, the other side is reset.  If you have two touch events simultaneously on opposite sides, they are both constantly setting their side and resetting the other side.  The resulting behavior will be "uncontrollable" as you said.

**The Solution**

You need to keep track of the state of your UI.  Specifically, you need to track of your touch locations.

During `touchesBegan()`, you add the location to the set of tracked touches.  During `touchesEnded()`, you remove the location from the set of tracked touches.  During `touchesMoved()`, you determine which tracked touch is closest to the moved touch object, and update it accordingly.

Each time your set is updated, you'll parse your tracked touch set and update the rotations of your nodes accordingly.  If a node has no touch that rotates it, it is then reset.  This function would probably be best called after the `for touch in touches` loop.

Comment: thank you for your answer! how would I go about creating a list of tracked touches?

Comment: Likely just a set (like an array) of locations (probably CGPoints).  touchesBegan, you add one for every touch.  touchesEnded, you remove one for every touch.  touchesMoved, you replace one for every touch.

Comment: I’m a beginner with swift so I’m learning as I go. In touchesMoved how do i replace the correct CGPoint in the array? Also how do I remove the correct CGPoint?

Comment: The simplest way is to simply use the closest tracked touch to the current touch.  Each touch object has a location, even when the touch is ending, and they should update frequently enough that they are never very far from their previous location.